# How to tweak d3 axis attributes when transition is present?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using the d3 axis component but I want to tweak a few things after it is drawn. Specifically I would like to rotate the text labels by adding a transform to the text elements and also setting the text-anchor attribute from "middle" to "end".

The problem I'm hitting is that the text-anchor attribute seems to be set asynchronously by the d3 code as part of the transition. When I set the value to "end" in my code it subsequently gets set back to "middle" when the transition runs.

If I wait until transition end before making my change it's going to look choppy. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to insert myself into the process of drawing and transitioning the axis such that my text-anchor value will be used instead of the default one?

Comment: This is difficult to solve without some code, but perhaps you could set the value at the transition start, ex: selection.on("start", function(){label.attr("text-anchor", "end")})

Comment: Please show some code. I'm not sure there's a way to smoothly transition the `text-anchor` attribute, though, as there are no intermediary values between "middle" and "end".

Comment: I'm not trying to transition text-anchor.  I just want to set it to "end" but the internals of d3 axis set it "middle" (asynchronously when in a transition).  The code I'm using is nothing more than a select for all <text> elements and an attr() call to set text-anchor.  It's the timing that is the tricky part when the d3 axis is rendered in a transition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this constitutes a bug in the axis component, so I've created a pull request to [update label attributes immediately](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/684) rather than as part of the axis transition. The text element's text-anchor attribute can't be interpolated, so there's no reason to defer the update to the transition, and setting it immediately makes it easy for you to fix it using post-selection.

An alternate fix would be to extend the axis component to support different styles of tick labeling. This way, you wouldn't need to use post-selection, so there's no conflict with the axis transition.

Comment: I've been debugging this in nvd3 for a day now when I came across this - turned out we were using 2.9.2 which didn't have the fix :)

Answer (score 2):

This seems something that can't be overridden from the API. A simple but hacky solution would be setting it in your stylesheet...

```
.x.axis text {
  text-anchor: end !important;
}
```

Comment: I actually didn't realize you could set this via stylesheet!  It seems to work even without !important so I guess the style takes precedence over the property.  Not sure if that's true on all browsers, though.  It's not beautiful because now there are 2 contradictory text-anchor values set on the same element, but it works, so thank you!!