# How to transition D3 axis without tick text attribute reset?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 project where I'm drawing a time axis along the left side of the screen. I want to have it smoothly transition on window resize so I'm using D3 transitions. However the axis setup appears to be changing the "dy" attribute on the tick labels immediately causing the tick labels to jump downward and then transition back into their normal place any time the SVG is transitioned. Is there any way to set the "dy" attribute of the tick text as part of the axis call or a better way to transition?

My initial (one-time) axis setup:

```
var timeScale = d3.time.scale().domain([minTime, maxTime]);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(timeScale).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%-m/%-d %-I:%M%p")).orient("right");
```

I have a function to update/transition the SVG elements I'm using. The first time the SVG is drawn init is set to true, false afterwards.

```
function updateSVG(init) {        
    ...
    timeScale.rangeRound([topPadding, svgHeight]);
    // Use a transition to update the axis if this is an update
    var t = (init) ? svgContainer : svgContainer.transition().duration(750);
    // {1}: Create Y axis
    t.select("g.axis").call(yAxis);
    // {2}: Move Y axis labels to the left side
    t.selectAll("g.tick > text")
        .attr("x", 4)
        .attr("dy", -4);
    ...
}
```

On an update at {1} tick labels all have a "dy" attribute of "-4" from the previous attr() call. At {2} applying the axis resets the "dy" attribute of these elements to a default of ".32em" after which they transition slowly back to "-4" causing them to jitter up and down as the window is resized and the axis is redrawn.

Here is a working JSFiddle that demonstrates the jump on the y-axis when the Result box is resized, resize just by a few pixels and it should be obvious: http://jsfiddle.net/YkDk4/1/

Comment: Why are you setting offsets for the tick values? It's usually better to adjust the scale/axis.

Comment: By making the tick size equal to the svg width I have background grid lines drawn on my SVG. I want the labels to sit above the grid lines and not drawn over top of them so I shifted the tick labels up slightly.

Comment: If I understand correctly it should work by just using `svgContainer` instead of `t` to do the offsets -- http://jsfiddle.net/YkDk4/2/

Comment: Hmm, definitely working in the JSFiddle here, but when combined with the background grid lines and reversing the orientation (see: http://jsfiddle.net/YkDk4/3/) using the container sends the labels to the opposite side of the graph. By using the "transform" attribute rather than "dy" (as I wrote below) and the transition everything seems to work naturally (see: http://jsfiddle.net/YkDk4/4/). Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, there's certainly more than one way to skin the cat!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured this out. By applying a "transform" attribute instead of a "dy" attribute the axis call() does not overwrite the value. So:

```
t.selectAll("g.tick > text")
    .attr("x", 4)
    .attr("dy", -4);
```

becomes:

```
t.selectAll("g.tick > text")
    .attr("x", 4)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,-4)");
```

and everything transitions smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bug fix made in response to this problem with the text-anchor attribute:

[How to tweak d3 axis attributes when transition is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181186/how-to-tweak-d3-axis-attributes-when-transition-is-present)

It looks like the dy attribute is supposed to update immediately during transitions...but it's not.

In any case, the easiest solution is simply to take the dy update OUT of the transition and apply it directly:

```
t.select(".y")
.call(yAxis);

chartSvg.selectAll(".y g.tick > text")
.attr("dy", -4);
```

That should avoid the "bounce".

Comment: I don't think you really understood the question. I **wanted** both the axis line and the tick labels to transition and not update immediately.